# SQL Server Replication: cannot open file (OS Error 5) even though I can manually log in as the executing user and open the file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a remote server running SQL Server 9.0.3042, trying to subscribe to a publication on a server running SQL Server 10.0.2531.

These servers are on different domains which basically hate each other and largely refuse to allow their users access to each other.

They do both communicate nicely with a third domain, and it is a user from that domain which I am using as the process owner on both servers.

I have created a shared folder on the publishing server, and I am using it as the Snapshot folder, set via Publication Properties -> Snapshot -> "Put files in the following folder" and have confirmed that the files are being published locally and can be accessed via the shared folder.

The Snapshot Agent on the publishing server runs and appears to complete successfully.

I've then created a Pull subscription on the subscribing server and told it to run with the Agent Process Account of the same user that runs the snapshot agent on the publisher.

I've redirected the snapshot location to "Alternate folder" and set that folder to be the shared folder on the remote server that I set up earlier.

The Pulling server connects correctly to the Publishing server, And then fails because "The process could not read file "\[server].[domain][share][snapshot directory][file].pre" due to OS error 5"

I've logged into the Pull server as the executing account and manually navigated to, and opened, that file. I've done the same on the publishing server.

I'm out of ideas. What am I screwing up?

Comment: When you 'manually navigated to and opened the file', did you use the share or go directly to the file location?

Comment: Both. The error message specifically references the share, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision has been taken that we're pretty much on the point where we're going to move every user in the company over to a brand new domain, and that this problem isn't worth the time and effort of fixing.

I did find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168883/sql-replication-setup-almost-there) which relates a similar problem, but I don't intend to investigate this matter any further.

Answer (score 0):

`OS Error 5` is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. You're not being allowed to get to the folder. Check to make sure that the user account trying to get to the files has at least read access to the folder containing the files.